# How to connect database connectivity with SharePoint 2013 web portal

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have created SharePoint online website, log in from a trial account.
Is it possible to open that website on SharePoint designer?

Comment: Do you have any further questions? Please remember to accept helpful answer if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could open SharePoint Online site in the SharePoint designer.

Comment: @emily-du-msft  How I can do, Please help me.